# Fetching Request headers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, siteminder

In Java, we can get http request header from HttpServletRequest.

`Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames(); // request is HttpServletRequest`

For our application we are trying to integrate SiteMinder with angularjs. In order to get user attributes after successful login, we need to extract data from request header. We are trying to construct a URL which will be the target and on successful authentication SiteMinder will redirect user to this URL. For example : the URL will be like this http://example.com/appContextRoot/testSM (where testSM is a state of angularjs)

```
$stateProvider.state('testSM', {
            parent: '...',
            url: '/testSM',
            data: {
                authorities: []
            },
            views: {                 
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: '',
                    controller: 'TestSMController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                } 
            },
```

Is there any way to get the attributes from request header as done in Java in angularjs after SiteMinder redirect user to this URL?

Answer (score 0):

No. Angular is Javascript - it runs in the browser. The request headers are injected between the SiteMinder web agent and you server-side application. They are not sent to the browser. What you need to do is make you server-side app (e.g. REST web services) expose the attributes so they can be queried by the browser. However do so with extreme caution - many headers provide sensitive PII or infrastructure detail information and are not meant to be exposed to the browser side. If you stick to simple values like username, email address, first & last name etc. then you should be OK.

Comment: Than You Richard for your inputs! We have thought of this approach also, but our doubt is how to ensure that the login flow does not break. Because once angular sends data to siteminder and siteminder posts the validation result to back en rest API how can we get the control back to angular? Can you please elaborate on  - "expose the attributes so they can be queried by the browser"

Comment: What you really are looking for is a way is to encapsulate the capabilities of SiteMinder (login, SSO, session mgmt, access control etc.) into your REST model. SiteMinder and similar products were built literally over two decades ago, long before Javascript and signle-page apps evolved to what they are today. Simple example, you probably don't want the user being redirected to another URL to log in, because then your app loses control of the experience. What I've done is build a set of REST services that do login, session validation, access queries etc. that can be invoked from Javascript

Comment: "expose attributes" - lets say you have a simple JSP running on you server that is behind a SiteMinder web agent. <%= "{ loginname: " + request.getHeader("SM_USER") + "; }"%> would be a simple JSP to print the login name from SiteMinder as a JSon response. So long as your javascript sends the SiteMinder cookie in the request, you'll be able to get the user's login name (beware CORS restrictions and HttpOnly cookies). At the risk of self promoting, I've created a product that provides 30 or so different microservices around SiteMinder, https://www.idfconnect.com/products/sso-rest/